# Why does this map define an $n$-dimensional manifold?

Tags: manifolds, hilbert-spaces

Let $0<\xi_1 <\xi_2<\ldots <\xi_n<1$ be $n$ variables, $\xi=(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)$; and $\Gamma=\{\xi|0<\xi_1<\ldots <\xi_n<1\}$.

Let $U(\cdot,\cdot)\colon\Gamma\times [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function for which we know that $U(\xi,\cdot)$ is a continuous function with a piecewise continuous first derivative.

> > Then, the map $\xi\to U(\xi,\cdot)$ defines an $n$-dimensional manifold $W\subset H^1$.

I think what is meant is that $W=\{U(\xi,\cdot):\xi\in\Gamma\}\subset H^1$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold. But I do not understand *why*.

Maybe someone could give me an explanation.

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: It’s from a paper from Fusco and Hale (1989) about slow motion manifolds.

Comment: What is meant by $H^1$?

Comment: It’s the Sobolev space

Comment: Can you be more specific? How many dimensions does it have, how is it defined, does it have a topology, how does it relate to $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or $\Bbb{C}^n$)?

Answer (score 3):

You must be missing some additional information. For example, if $U(\xi,\cdot)\equiv 0$, then it fulfills your assumptions, but $W=\{0\}$ is a single point, so cannot be an $n$-dimensional manifold.